# perl remove last column of tab-delimited file

Tags: perl

I'm loading and printing tab-delimited files in my perl script. However the last column of my input file ($table1) is empty and I don't want to print this in my output file ($table3). How and where should I do this? After the 'open' or at the end in the 'print $table3'?

This is part of my script (... denotes code not important for this question)

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
use Getopt::Long qw(GetOptions);;

...

open(my $table1,'<', $input) or die "$! - [$input]"; #input file 
open(my $table3, '+>', $output) || die ("Can't write new file: $!"); #output file

...

chomp( my @header_for_table1 = split /\t/, <$table1> );

print $table3 join "\t", @header_for_table1, "name1", "name2", "\n";

{
    no warnings 'uninitialized';
    while(<$table1>){
         chomp;
         my %row;
         @row{@header_for_table1} = split /\t/;
         print $table3 join ( "\t", @row{@header_for_table1},
                   @{ $lookup{ ... }
                        // [ "", "" ] }), "\n";
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just `pop @header_for_table1` which will remove the last header, and so store one less column in the hash slice. But I imagine that the "extra" column has come from code like this which has the newline in the parameter list for `join "\t", ..., "\n"` so it would be best just to remove the tab immediately before the newline with `s/\t?\n\z//` instead of using `chomp`

I recommend that you put some parentheses around your `join` parameters, otherwise you are going to create more files with a spare tab at the end of each line. Here's a refactoring of the code you have shown which makes this and some other improvements

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
use Getopt::Long qw(GetOptions);

my ($input, $output);
my %lookup;

...;

open my $in_fh,  '<', $input  or die "$! - [$input]";

...;

my @header = do {
    my $header = <$in_fh>;
    $header =~ s/\t?\n\z//;
    split /\t/, $header;
};

open my $out_fh, '>', $output or die "Can't write new file: $!";

print $out_fh join("\t", @header, qw/ name1 name2 /), "\n";

while ( <$in_fh> ) {
     s/\t?\n\z//;

     my @row = split /\t/;

     my $names = $lookup{ ... };
     my @names = $names ? @$names : ('', '');

     print $out_fh join("\t", @row, @names), "\n";
}
```